# Border-Radius on Corners of Table Not Working

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I have an email template [here](http://rainleader.com/basic.html) that has CSS styling applied to make the edges rounded.

I want the top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right outer corners to be rounded. All internal table edges/corners should be square.

You can see, though, that it's rounding the internal edges, too:

Header:

[image]

Footer:

[image]

How should I modify my CSS to ONLY round outside edges/corners?

```
table {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
/* Top Left */
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
/* Top Right */
table tr:first-child th:last-child{
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
/* Bottom Left */
table tr:last-child td:first-child{
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
/* Bottom Right */
table tr:last-child td:last-child{
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the shorthand, so,

For Header (`#templateHeader`),

```
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; /*top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left*/
```

[image]

For Footer (`#templateFooter`),

```
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you are applying the `border-radius` to `td` element, in order to see the rounded border based on your DOM organization, you must apply the border-radius to the `table` element.

Answer (score 0):

nothing.
the border-radius property is not supported by Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm able to see the rounded edges just fine, my problem is making it so ONLY the outer edges are rounded (not internal ones). Added screenshots showing the problem areas.